# How to get text after selected parameter in PHP

Tags: php

so basically I have a .txt file with over thousands of rows such as:

```
badge_name_xxx=Name goes here 
badge_desc_xxx=Text goes here 
badge_name_xox=You get the drift 
badge_desc_xox=Do you understand?
```

So what I'm trying to do is grab the text after the `=` so that I can echo it. I've tried things such as:

```
$file = "/game/gamedata/external_flash_texts.txt";
$badge = "XOX";
$f = fopen($file, 'rb');
$found = false;
while ($line = fgets($f, 1000)) {
    if ($found) {
       echo $line;
       continue;
    }
    if (strpos($line, "BADGE_NAME_" . $badge . "=") !== FALSE) {
      $found = true;
      echo $found;
    }
}
```

I've also tried

```
$data = file_get_contents("/game/gamedata/external_flash_texts.txt"); 
$badge= "ADM";   
$whatIWant = substr($badge, strpos($data, "=") + 1);    
echo $whatIWant;
```

And many other methods, but can't seem to find one that works. The location of this PHP script is in the ROOT folder, and the .txt file is located in the directory in the script. What am I doing wrong? I'm convinced I'm not approaching this the right way.

Comment: why don't you just do an [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)?

Comment: @Jeff I'm not aware of explode, more than welcome to show me an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getBadgeValue($name)
{
    $pathToFile = "/game/gamedata/external_flash_texts.txt";
    $file = new SplFileObject($pathToFile);

    foreach($file as $line)
    {
        $data = explode("=", $line);

        if(count($data) < 2)
        {
            continue;
        }

        //map first element to $key and second element to $value
        list($key, $value) = $data;

        if($key === $name)
        {
            //found, so return the value
            return $value;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

echo getBadgeValue('badge_name_xox'); //outputs "You get the drift"
```

Function getBadgeValue() will return value of your badge or null if there's no such badge in the file

If this function doesn't do what you want then either you didn't tell us exactly what you want to do or you've made a mistake somewhere (wrong path to file?)

**Also, remember to wrap a code that does one thing into a function, so you** [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

If you want **case insensitivity** then just change this line:

```
if($key === $name)
```

to:

```
if(strtolower($key) === $name)
```

and at the beginning of the function add

```
$name = strtolower($name);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = "/game/gamedata/external_flash_texts.txt";
$badge = "XOX";

foreach(new SplFileObject($file) as $line) {
    $parts = explode('=', $line, 2);
    $badge_suffix = substr(strtolower($parts[0]), -strlen($badge));
    if ($badge_suffix===strtolower($badge) && count($parts) > 1) {
        echo $parts[1];
    }
}
```

EDIT: Updated answer to select only the required badge.

EDIT: Make case insensitive so 'XOX' matches 'xox'

Comment: I need to include the $data, where all the text is stored.

Comment: Also this example is no where near what I'm trying to achieve. I need to be able to CALL the badge name (or desc) and output the data. The txt file does not just include that, there's other parameters in the page.

Comment: I saw "So what I'm trying to do is grab the text after the = so that I can echo it".  Didn't think I'd have to repeat all the code.  Also, didn't see anything about "CALL the badge name".  What do you mean "CALL the badge name"?  Is badge name the name of one of your PHP functions?

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = file_get_contents("text.txt");
$file = explode("\n", $file); //split into lines
foreach($file as $key => $value) {
    $v = explode('=', $value); //split between =
    echo $v[1].'<br>'; //display anything after =
}
```

Comment: Pro-tip:  `$file = file("text.txt");` and `$file` is already an array. No explosions required ;)

Comment: An even better thing to learn is `SplFileObject`.  Both `file` and `file_get_contents` read the entire file into memory.  Not good if you are dealing with a big file.  `SplFileObject` does not read the entire file at once.  It also implements the iterator so you can use it as is in a `foreach`:  `$file = new SplFileObject("text.txt"); foreach ($file as $line) {}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to read each line of `file.txt` to an array and then use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the string on `=`, where `[0]` is the **1st** part and `[1]` the **2nd**, i.e.:

```
foreach (file("file.txt") as $line) {
    echo explode("=", $line)[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

I'm not sure about the performance of preg_match_all in this case if you want to load a large amount of rows, but it is at least ***one*** way to pick up all the values you're looking for in one fetch - and get the use of both (in this case) name and description wherever you want afterwards.

```
$file = "/game/gamedata/external_flash_texts.txt";
$badge="xox";
preg_match_all("/badge_(.*?)_{$badge}=(.*?)\n/i", $rows, $outData);
$keyArray=array();
// If there is no count, we'd consider $badge not found
if (count($outData[1])) {
    foreach ($outData[1] as $keyIdx => $key) {
        $keyArray[$key] = isset($outData[2][$keyIdx])? $outData[2][$keyIdx] :"";
    }
    $found = true;
    echo "Found! Description: " . $keyArray['desc'] . "\n";
}
```